# jQuery .ajax method executing but not firing error (or success)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I'm having a very strange situation.  I have a .NET Web Service (.asmx) that I'm trying to call via jQuery ajax to populate some `<select></select>`'s.  The service is running `System.Web.Services` like it's supposed to and should be returning a JSON list.  At least that's the way I understand that it will in .NET 3.5/4.0.

The main problem is that the `.ajax()` function (below) seems to execute but the internal callbacks aren't executing.  I know it's executing because I can do something before and after the function and both execute, so JavaScript isn't blowing up.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'http://localhost:59191/AFEDropDownService/Service.asmx/GetAVP',
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(list) {
        console.log(list);
        console.log("success!!");
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        console.log("error: " + msg.text);
    }
});
```

If you need more of the code let me know.  Or if you know a better way as I'm trying to build cascading `<select></select`'s.

### Update

I changed it from "jsonp" to "json", now I'm back to the error message of "undefined".  Is there anyway to find out **WHAT** is undefined?  I'm afraid I'm in a bit over my head.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'http://localhost:59191/AFEDropDownService/Service.asmx/GetAVP',
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(list) {
        console.log(list);
        console.log("success!!");
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        //console.log("error: " + msg.text);
    }
});
```

### Update 2

I put in the following `.ajaxError()` code and it shows an "empty string" in firebug for the "thrownError" object.

```
$("#sel_AFE").ajaxError(function(e,xhr,settings,thrownError){
    console.log('error in: ' + settings.url + ' \n'+'error:\n' + thrownError);
});
```

Comment: You are developing locally, so why `jsonp/cross-domain`?

Comment: For some reason it give me an "undefined" error when I don't.  Probably because the IDE (Visual Studio) uses different ports for the service and client.

Comment: it could just be that console.log is your issue. Have you tried just using alert(list); to see what is being returned or using firebug/chrome console to watch for the query

Comment: Why don't you use just json instead of jsonp.. Also why did you set the cross domain..

DO you see your jsonp data in the response section of the browser..??

Comment: If you aren't getting the error callback or the success callback, you should be getting a js error.

Comment: Also use Instead of  error: function(msg){console.log("error: " + msg.text);} .. try Using                                         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){// log all the details here}

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use just json instead of jsonp.. Also why did you set the cross domain..

DO you see your jsonp data in the response section of the browser..??

Also use Instead of

```
error: function(msg){
       console.log("error: " + msg.text);
 } .. try Using 

error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  // log all the details here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) say:

> If a request with jQuery.post() returns an error code, it will fail
>   silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError()
>   method. Alternatively, as of jQuery 1.5, the .error() method of the
>   jqXHR object returned by jQuery.post() is also available for error
>   handling.

And here is an example of how to use `success` and `error` callbacks:

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.post("example.php", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });

// perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.complete(function(){ alert("second complete"); });
```

Comment: This is very helpful.  I did the following:

$("#sel_AFE").ajaxError(function(e,xhr,settings,exception){
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
    });

to catch the error, but I'm still stuck with the "undefined" error message.  Is there something that can tell me what is "undefined"?